# Where to Add text file on an Android Studio Project to place internal comments that won't be deployed on APK

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-project-template

I want to add a text file on Android Studio where to place internal comments, ideas, development status, pendings, etc.

The issue is that I don't want this file to be part of deployment APK's, but I want to have it inside Android Studio project for simplicity.

I found somewhere that suggest to put it at resources folder:  `res/raw`, but this content will be deployed on APK and I don't want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `notes/` directory off of the project root. Or a `docs/` directory. Or whatever you want.

Everything inside of `src/` for a module is a candidate for being included in an APK. Conversely, stuff in directories that Android Studio does not know about (e.g., `notes/`, `docs/`, `super-sekrit-stuff/`) will not be included in an APK, unless you do something specific in the Gradle build files to request that they be included.

Answer (score 1):

Just put it top level, right into your project folder and above *`app`*. Similar files such as the `README`, `COPYING` and `BUILDING` are placed there. For more info just search a bit through GitHub and you will find plenty of such structural examples.